# Fetch facebook data using javascript FB.api not working when not logged in

Tags: facebook

I have the following code to display the users on my site.

```
function getFBData()
{
    FB.api(
    '/*fbID*/',
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /*CODE*/
      }
    }
    );
}
getFBData();
```

It was working fine when a user is logged in, via Facebook plugin, into the site. But nothing is fetched when the user is not logged in.

Is a user really needed to be logged in to execute FB.api?

Answer (score 0):

Actually user must be logged in to Facebook to use Facebook Api,
you can use the code below to check the state of the user to either get his data if connected or ask him to login again.

```
  FB.init({
             appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',          
             channelUrl: '//www.yoursite.com/fbsdk-channel.aspx',   
             status: true,                  
             cookie: true,                  
             xfbml: true,                   
             oauth: true
         });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {   
 /* The user has already logged into FB but not authorized the your webpage */
        }
        else if (response.status === 'connected') {
 /* The user has logged into FB and authorized the "App" to get their user information */
    }
    else { /* The user has not yet logged into FB */ }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Since my website is a quiz website, I am trying to display the top scorers on my landing page, not the information of the current visitor. Could it be possible? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I think you can save every Facebook user's who log in to your website Name & ImageURL in your system & retrieve the top scorers from your system's data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, you CAN use FB.api without authorization, but only for API calls that need an App Access Token. For API calls with a User Token, you do need authorization. Of course you can´t grab details of a user (by ID) without authborization, so in your case you must authorize the user.

More information about Access Tokens and login:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/